# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'root' on kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, kivy-language

I need to pass value to another class(screen) on kivy
this is my py code :

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder


class MyLayout(Screen):
    pstd=ObjectProperty(None)
    def save():
        pass

    def calculate(self):
        pstd=self.pstd.text
        pres=self.pres.text
        tres=self.tres.text
        tsep=self.tsep.text
        psep=self.psep.text
        api=self.api.text
        dg=self.sg.text
        pb=self.pb.text
        co2=self.co2.text
        h2s=self.h2s.text
        n2=self.n2.text
        tds=self.tds.text
        if(self.sat.state == "down"):
            cond = 2
        else :
            cond = 1
        print(pstd)
        return pstd
        

    
class MyLayout2(Screen):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        print(App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('main').calculate())
        


    
class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass
kv = Builder.load_file("tubes1.kv")

class TubesApp(App):
    my_layout = MyLayout()
    def build(self):
        return kv

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TubesApp().run()
```

and this is my kv code :

```
WindowManager:
    MyLayout:
    MyLayout2:

<MyLayout>:
    name: "main"
    free:free
    sat:sat
    pstd:pstd
    tres:tres
    pres:pres
    tsep:tsep
    psep:psep
    api:api
    sg:sg
    pb:pb
    co2:co2
    h2s:h2s
    n2:n2
    tds:tds
    btn:btn
    background_color : 71/255,213/255,223/255,1
    canvas.before:
        Color :
            rgba : self.background_color
        Rectangle :
            size : self.size
            pos : self.pos
    FloatLayout :
        size : root.width,root.height
        Label :
            text : "PVT Calculator"
            font_size : 20
            size_hint : (None,None)
            size : 400,100
            color: 1,1,1,1
            pos_hint : {"center_x":0.5,"top" : 1}
            background_color : (35/255,135/255,142/255,1)
            canvas.before:
                Color :
                    rgba : self.background_color
                Rectangle :
                    size : self.size
                    pos : self.pos
        Label :
            text : "Oil Data"
            font_size : 20
            size_hint : (0.5,0.09)
            color: 0.3,0.4,0.5,1
            pos_hint : {"center_x":0.25,"top" : 0.8}
            background_color : (71/255,220/255,141/255,1)
            canvas.before:
                Color :
                    rgba : self.background_color
                Rectangle :
                    size : self.size
                    pos : self.pos

        Label :
            text : "API"
            font_size : 12
            size_hint : (0.25,0.04)
            color: 1,1,1,1
            pos_hint : {"x":0, "top":0.712}
            background_color : (5/255,95/255,53/255,1)
            canvas.before:
                Color :
                    rgba : self.background_color
                Rectangle :
                    size : self.size
                    pos : self.pos
        TextInput :
            id:api
            multiline:False
            font_size : 12
            size_hint : (0.25,0.04)
            pos_hint : {"x":0.25, "top":0.712}

        Label :
            text : "Saturation pressure"
            font_size : 12
            size_hint : (0.25,0.04)
            color: 1,1,1,1
            pos_hint : {"x":0, "top":0.672}
            background_color : (6/255,124/255,69/255,1)
            canvas.before:
                Color :
                    rgba : self.background_color
                Rectangle :
                    size : self.size
                    pos : self.pos
        TextInput :
            id:pb
            multiline:False
            font_size : 12
            size_hint : (0.25,0.04)
            pos_hint : {"x":0.25, "top":0.672}

        Label :
            text : "Spesific Gravity"
            font_size : 12
            size_hint : (0.25,0.04)
            pos_hint : {"x":0, "top":0.632}
            color: 1,1,1,1
            background_color : (8/255,152/255,85/255,1)
            canvas.before:
                Color :
                    rgba : self.background_color
                Rectangle :
                    size : self.size
                    pos : self.pos
        TextInput : 
            id:sg
            multiline:False
            font_size : 12
            size_hint : (0.25,0.04)
            pos_hint : {"x":0.25, "top":0.632}

        Label : 
            text : "Non-Hydrocarbon Component"
            font_size : 20
            size_hint : (0.5,0.09)
            color: 0.3,0.4,0.5,1
            pos_hint : {"center_x":0.75,"top" : 0.8}
            background_color : (14/255,195/255,110/225,1)
            canvas.before:
                Color :
                    rgba : self.background_color
                Rectangle :
                    size : self.size
                    pos : self.pos
        Label :
            text : "CO2"
            font_size : 12
            size_hint : (0.25,0.04)
            color: 1,1,1,1
            pos_hint : {"x":0.5, "top":0.712}
            background_color : (5/255,95/255,53/255,1)
            canvas.before:
                Color :
                    rgba : self.background_color
                Rectangle :
                    size : self.size
                    pos : self.pos
        TextInput : 
            id:co2
            multiline:False
            font_size : 12
            size_hint : (0.25,0.04)
            pos_hint : {"x":0.75, "top":0.712}

        Label :
            text : "H2S"
            font_size : 12
            size_hint : (0.25,0.04)
            color: 1,1,1,1
            pos_hint : {"x":0.5, "top":0.672}
            background_color : (6/255,124/255,69/255,1)
            canvas.before:
                Color :
                    rgba : self.background_color
                Rectangle :
                    size : self.size
                    pos : self.pos
        TextInput : 
            id:h2s
            multiline:False
            font_size : 12
            size_hint : (0.25,0.04)
            pos_hint : {"x":0.75, "top":0.672}

        Label :
            text : "N2"
            font_size : 12
            size_hint : (0.25,0.04)
            color: 1,1,1,1
            pos_hint : {"x":0.5, "top":0.632}
            background_color : (8/255,152/255,85/255,1)
            canvas.before:
                Color :
                    rgba : self.background_color
                Rectangle :
                    size : self.size
                    pos : self.pos
        TextInput : 
            id:n2
            multiline:False
            font_size : 12
            size_hint : (0.25,0.04)
            pos_hint : {"x":0.75, "top":0.632}

        Label :
            text : "Reservoir and Separator Data"
            font_size : 20
            size_hint : (0.5,0.09)
            color: 0.3,0.4,0.5,1
            pos_hint : {"center_x":0.25,"top" : 0.5}
            background_color : (14/255,195/255,110/225,1)
            canvas.before:
                Color :
                    rgba : self.background_color
                Rectangle :
                    size : self.size
                    pos : self.pos
        Label :
            text : "Reservoir Temperature"
            font_size : 12
            size_hint : (0.25,0.04)
            pos_hint : {"x":0, "top":0.41}
            color: 1,1,1,1
            background_color : (5/255,95/255,53/255,1)
            canvas.before:
                Color :
                    rgba : self.background_color
                Rectangle :
                    size : self.size
                    pos : self.pos
        TextInput : 
            id:tres
            multiline:False
            font_size : 12
            size_hint : (0.25,0.04)
            pos_hint : {"x":0.25, "top":0.41}

        Label :
            text : "Initial Reservoir pressure"
            font_size : 12
            size_hint : (None,None)
            size : 200,25
            color: 1,1,1,1
            pos : 0,200
            background_color : (6/255,124/255,69/255,1)
            canvas.before:
                Color :
                    rgba : self.background_color
                Rectangle :
                    size : self.size
                    pos : self.pos
        TextInput : 
            id:pres
            multiline:False
            font_size : 12
            size_hint : (None,None)
            size : 200,25
            pos : 200,200

        Label :
            text : "Separator Temperature"
            font_size : 12
            size_hint : (None,None)
            size : 200,25
            color: 1,1,1,1
            pos : 0,175
            background_color : (8/255,152/255,85/255,1)
            canvas.before:
                Color :
                    rgba : self.background_color
                Rectangle :
                    size : self.size
                    pos : self.pos
        TextInput : 
            id:tsep
            multiline:False
            font_size : 12
            size_hint : (None,None)
            size : 200,25
            pos : 200,175

        Label :
            text : "Separator pressure"
            font_size : 12
            size_hint : (None,None)
            size : 200,25
            color: 1,1,1,1
            pos : 0,150
            background_color : (9/255,181/255,101/255,1)
            canvas.before:
                Color :
                    rgba : self.background_color
                Rectangle :
                    size : self.size
                    pos : self.pos
        TextInput :
            id:psep
            multiline:False
            font_size : 12
            size_hint : (None,None)
            size : 200,25
            pos : 200,150

        Label :
            text : "Standard pressure"
            font_size : 12
            size_hint : (None,None)
            size : 200,25
            color: 1,1,1,1
            pos : 0,125
            background_color : (10/255,209/255,116/255,1)
            canvas.before:
                Color :
                    rgba : self.background_color
                Rectangle :
                    size : self.size
                    pos : self.pos
        TextInput : 
            id:pstd
            multiline:False
            font_size : 12
            size_hint : (None,None)
            size : 200,25
            pos : 200,125

        Label :
            text : "Water Formation Data"
            font_size : 20
            size_hint : (0.5,0.09)
            color: 0.3,0.4,0.5,1
            pos_hint : {"center_x":0.75,"top" : 0.5}
            background_color : (71/255,220/255,141/255,1)
            canvas.before:
                Color :
                    rgba : self.background_color
                Rectangle :
                    size : self.size
                    pos : self.pos
            Label :
                size_hint : (None,None)
                size : 400,125
                color: 0.3,0.4,0.5,1
                pos: 400,125
                background_color : (5/255,95/255,53/255,1)
                canvas.before:
                    Color :
                        rgba : self.background_color
                    Rectangle :
                        size : self.size
                        pos : self.pos

            Label :
                text : "Condition"
                font_size : 12
                size_hint : (None,None)
                size : 400,25
                color: 1,1,1,1
                pos : 400,225
                background_color : (6/255,124/255,69/255,1)
                canvas.before:
                    Color :
                        rgba : self.background_color
                    Rectangle :
                        size : self.size
                        pos : self.pos
            ToggleButton :
                id:sat
                text : "Gas-Saturated Brine"
                size_hint : (None,None)
                size : 180, 60
                pos : 420, 155
                group : 'Condition'
     
            ToggleButton :
                id:free
                text : "Gas-Free Brine"
                size_hint : (None,None)
                size : 180, 60
                pos : 610, 155
                group : 'Condition'
                state: "normal" 
                    

            Label :
                text : "Total Dissolved Solid"
                font_size : 12
                size_hint : (None,None)
                size : 200,25
                color: 1,1,1,1
                pos : 400,125
                background_color : (10/255,209/255,116/255,1)
                canvas.before:
                    Color :
                        rgba : self.background_color
                    Rectangle :
                        size : self.size
                        pos : self.pos
            TextInput : 
                id:tds
                multiline:False
                font_size : 12
                size_hint : (None,None)
                size : 200,25
                pos : 600,125
        
        Button :
            id:btn
            text : "CALCULATE"
            size_hint : (None,None)
            size : 180, 60
            pos_hint : {"center_x":0.5,"y":0.05}
            on_press : root.calculate()
            on_release : app.root.current = "second"

<MyLayout2>:

    name : "second"
    ubah:ubah
    GridLayout :
        cols : 1
        Label :
            id:ubah
            text : "test"
        Button :
            text : "Back"
            on_press : root.press()
            on_release : app.root.current = "main"
```

its working if im using def ...() instead of def **init**() but i need to use **init** in this case.
It always says 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'root' when im using App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('second').press()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These changes should help.

Add the **super** method, and I also added a print statement just for information.

```
class MyLayout(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        print(kwargs)
```

And also in this class add the **super** call inside the *init*_ method.  I also added a method **press**, that connects to the button press event that you had entered in your .kv file.
The reason that App.get_running_app() does not work in this case is because the run() method has not executed when this is initialized.  It is not running at this point.... and so I commented your line

```
class MyLayout2(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        print(kwargs)
        # print(App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('main').calculate())
    def press(self):
        print("you pressed Back from {}".format(self))
```

I added an **on_start** method here and some print statements that may help you.  Honestly I don't know what is intended with the calculate() statement at this point.

```
class TubesApp(App):
    my_layout = MyLayout()

    def build(self):
        return kv

    def on_start(self) -> None:
        print(type(App.get_running_app()))
        print(type(App.get_running_app().root))
        print(type(App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('main')))
        # print(App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('main').calculate())
```

With these changes your app launches and moves to the second window when the **Calculate** button is pressed and it moves back when the **Back** button is pressed

Comment: Thank you, that makes me understand better